Executing LibreOffice Macro from ASP.NET Web App (IIS)
I'm encountering challenges running a LibreOffice macro using soffice from my ASP.NET web application hosted in IIS.
Locally (outside IIS), I could execute the macro with the following command from application started using Visual Studio or command prompt:
soffice.exe --headless "macro:///Standard.Test.Main("C:/Macro/1/WorkProcedure.xlsx","file:///C:/Macro/1/")"

Since the hosted application uses a different user (IIS AppPool user) compared to my development environment, the above command no longer works.
I tried using the -env:UserInstallation argument but haven't achieved success with the following command:
soffice.exe -env:UserInstallation="file:///C:/Macro/" --headless "C:/Macro/TestMacro.ods" "macro://TestMacro/Standard.Test.Main("C:/Macro/1/WorkProcedure.xlsx","file:///C:/Macro/1/")"

Are there any solutions or configurations that might make this functionality works within IIS?

You will have to know very well what are the resources used by that command and then determine what settings (file permissions etc.) must be changed. Unfortunately, that's not a common knowledge everyone knows. Hope someone can give you further guidance, or you have to dig into LibreOffice source code yourself.
